# Android Kotlin SQLite - create table in real time

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, create-table

Hi I have problem when I want to create new table through click the button like this

```
buttonAddTable.setOnClickListener {

            db?.execSQL("CREATE TABLE ${tabela}(" +
                    "${BaseColumns._ID} INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                    "${TableInfo.TABLE_COLUMN_TITLE} TEXT NOT NULL," +
                    "${TableInfo.TABLE_COLUMN_MESSAGE} TEXT NOT NULL)")
```

its ok and i can add date to it like this

```
if (intent.hasExtra("tabela")) {

                var tabela = intent.getCharSequenceExtra("tabela")
                var tab = tabela.toString()
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"This table is: "+tabela, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                val value = ContentValues()
                value.put(TableInfo.TABLE_COLUMN_TITLE, title)
                value.put(TableInfo.TABLE_COLUMN_MESSAGE, message)
                db.insert(tab, null, value)
```

work good but when i want show this table like this

```
if (intent.hasExtra("tabela")){

        var tabela = intent.getCharSequenceExtra("tabela")
        var tab = tabela.toString()
        val cursor = db.query(
            tab, null,
            null, null,
            null, null, null
        )
        val notes = ArrayList<Note>()
        if (cursor.count > 0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst()
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast) {
                val note = Note()
                note.id = cursor.getInt(0)
                note.title = cursor.getString(1)
                note.message = cursor.getString(2)
                notes.add(note)
                cursor.moveToNext()
            }
        }
        cursor.close()

        recyler_view.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(applicationContext, 2)
        recyler_view.adapter = CardViewAdapter(applicationContext, db, notes)
```

**i see error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1.**

**Why? What I'm doing wrong?**

when i create table in fun onCreate when the app first starts it's fine

**EDIT**
I'll show you everything, maybe it's easier to find an error: Add row

```
if (intent.hasExtra("tabela")) {

                var tabela = intent.getCharSequenceExtra("tabela")
                var tab = tabela.toString()
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"This table is: "+tabela, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                val value = ContentValues()
                value.put(TableInfo.TABLE_COLUMN_TITLE, title)
                value.put(TableInfo.TABLE_COLUMN_MESSAGE, message)
                db.insert(tab, null, value)

                Toast.makeText(
                    applicationContext,
                    "Notatka zapisana w konkretnej tabeli",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
                val intent = Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                db.close()
                onBackPressed()

            }else {



                val value = ContentValues()
                value.put(TableInfo.TABLE_COLUMN_TITLE, title)
                value.put(TableInfo.TABLE_COLUMN_MESSAGE, message)
                db.insert(TableInfo.TABLE_NAME, null, value)
                save_info_Toast.show()
                val intent = Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                db.close()
                onBackPressed()
            }
```

show row

```
val dbHelper = DataBaseHelper(applicationContext)
    val db = dbHelper.writableDatabase
    if (intent.hasExtra("tabela")){

        var tabela = intent.getCharSequenceExtra("tabela")
        var tab = tabela.toString()
        val cursor = db.query(
            tab, null,
            null, null,
            null, null, null
        )
        val notes = ArrayList<Note>()
        if (cursor.count > 0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst()
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast) {
                val note = Note()
                note.id = cursor.getInt(0)
                note.title = cursor.getString(1)
                note.message = cursor.getString(2)
                notes.add(note)
                cursor.moveToNext()
            }
        }
        cursor.close()

        recyler_view.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(applicationContext, 2)
        recyler_view.adapter = CardViewAdapter(applicationContext, db, notes)

    }else {

        val cursor = db.query(
            TableInfo.TABLE_NAME, null,
            null, null,
            null, null, null
        )
        val notes = ArrayList<Note>()


        if (cursor.count > 0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst()
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast) {
                val note = Note()
                note.id = cursor.getInt(0)
                note.title = cursor.getString(1)
                note.message = cursor.getString(2)
                notes.add(note)
                cursor.moveToNext()
            }
        }
        cursor.close()

        recyler_view.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(applicationContext, 2)
        recyler_view.adapter = CardViewAdapter(applicationContext, db, notes)

    }

}
```

and cardview

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    //------------ELEMENT POJEDYNCZEJ NOTATKI--------
    val cardView_note = holder.view.note_cardView
    val title = holder.view.title_cardView
    val message = holder.view.message_cardView
    val context: Context = holder.view.context

    //---------------------------------

    title.setText(notes[holder.adapterPosition].title)
    message.setText(notes[holder.adapterPosition].message)
}
```

Comment: Hi can you iterate columns of cursor via cursor.getColumnNames and show us the log ?

Comment: Are you sure that you can insert new rows in the table? Did you check the result value of `db.insert(tab, null, value)`?

Comment: I have one table which is created when the application is launched for the first time. And now when I create new table and new row I can show this new table but when I add row to table "Notes" I can still see this error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3.

Comment: I edit post now you can see almost everything

Comment: I found my error. In override fun getItemCount(): 
I still used the same table name stored in the variable. 
slight error 3 days of searching :/